# MS Edge: SCRIPT5022: Failed to link vertex and fragment shaders

Tags: microsoft-edge, tensorflow.js

I have run my simple tensorflow.js app on Chrome (Windows10), Android, and iOS - and it is working. But when I try to run on MS Edge (Windows10) I get this error:

```
Failed to create D3D shaders.
index.ts (67,1)
SCRIPT5022: Failed to link vertex and fragment shaders.
```

The error occurs when I am trying to make a prediction (so the GPU is used):

```
function predict() {
var cData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var cdata = cData.data; 
for (var i = 0; i < cdata.length; i += 4) { // to grayscale
  cdata[i] = (cdata[i] + cdata[i + 1] + cdata[i + 2]) / 3;
}

var x = tf.browser.fromPixels(cData, 1).asType('float32'); // keep only one channel 
x = tf.image.resizeNearestNeighbor(x, [28, 28]);    // resize
x = x.expandDims();
x = x.div(255);
var prediction;

tf.tidy(() => { 
const output = model.predict(x);
const axis = 1;
prediction = Array.from(output.argMax(axis).dataSync());
preds = output.arraySync();
});
}
```

The printout on the console:

```
C:\fakepath(114,28-43): warning X3556: integer divides may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(115,29-36): warning X3556: integer divides may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(106,7-48): error X3531: can't unroll loops marked with loop attribute

C:\fakepath(114,28-43): warning X3556: integer divides may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(115,29-36): warning X3556: integer divides may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(126,2-29): warning X3550: array reference cannot be used as an l-value; not natively addressable, forcing loop to unroll
C:\fakepath(126,2-29): error X3500: array reference cannot be used as an l-value; not natively addressable
C:\fakepath(106,7-48): error X3511: forced to unroll loop, but unrolling failed.
C:\fakepath(104,7-48): error X3511: forced to unroll loop, but unrolling failed.

Warning: D3D shader compilation failed with default flags. (ps_5_0)
 Retrying with skip validation
C:\fakepath(114,28-43): warning X3556: integer divides may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(115,29-36): warning X3556: integer divides may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(126,2-29): warning X3550: array reference cannot be used as an l-value; not natively addressable, forcing loop to unroll
C:\fakepath(126,2-29): error X3500: array reference cannot be used as an l-value; not natively addressable
C:\fakepath(106,7-48): error X3511: forced to unroll loop, but unrolling failed.
C:\fakepath(104,7-48): error X3511: forced to unroll loop, but unrolling failed.

Warning: D3D shader compilation failed with skip validation flags. (ps_5_0)
 Retrying with skip optimization
C:\fakepath(114,28-43): warning X3556: integer divides may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(115,29-36): warning X3556: integer divides may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(126,2-29): warning X3550: array reference cannot be used as an l-value; not natively addressable, forcing loop to unroll
C:\fakepath(126,2-29): error X3500: array reference cannot be used as an l-value; not natively addressable
C:\fakepath(106,7-48): error X3511: forced to unroll loop, but unrolling failed.
C:\fakepath(104,7-48): error X3511: forced to unroll loop, but unrolling failed.

Warning: D3D shader compilation failed with skip optimization flags. (ps_5_0)


Failed to create D3D shaders.
webgl_util.ts (155,5)

 SCRIPT5022: Failed to link vertex and fragment shaders.
```

Is it a problem with some browser setting? Is tensorflow.js supporting Edge? I guess it must support Edge. tfjs 1.0 is used.

Comment: No problem with Firefox (Ubuntu).

Comment: Similar issue but with Chrome: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1337.  Also I wonder if this is related to other WebGL-on-Windows issues: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1400.

Comment: Works with with tfjs 0.15.3 so something is changed...

Comment: Hi, can you run `tf.ENV.set('WEBGL_PACK', false)` at the very start of your js app, right after you load the TF.js library and let me know if it helps so we can narrow down the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Adding `tf.ENV.set('WEBGL_PACK', false)` fixed the problem with tfjs 1.0.1 and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded face-api.min.js to the 0.22.2 version and the error is gone.
Here is the source to latest version:
https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/