# Cannot load up a model with TensorFlow.js

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to load [this model](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/centernet/hourglass_512x512_kpts/1) and I found [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7gOYpT732ow)

So far I came up with [this](https://github.com/avi12/lego-ai.js/blob/bb41aa57d238798dc80cbc8861676645cd0e3d19/src/App.svelte#L46-L54), but I'm getting this error:

> Error: Failed to link vertex and fragment shaders.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow.js transforms the model into a bunch of GLSL shaders, small programs runnable on GPU.

This error means that the browser was unable to compile the GLSL code to run on your graphic card for some reason. Likely, the message does not come from TF, but from the in-browser WebGL implementation.

To ease identifying the exact cause of your issue, consider sharing your OS/hardware setup (namely, which browser you run and which GPU you have). The usual recommendation is to make sure your GPU is okay. Bear in mind that some low-end GPUs may be unable to run TensorFlow.js or some of its models at all. A good thing may be to try out the same code on a different machine (a desktop one with a good GPU).

A couple of related discussions (even though they do not point to a solution):

https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/issues/327

[MS Edge: SCRIPT5022: Failed to link vertex and fragment shaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55188619/ms-edge-script5022-failed-to-link-vertex-and-fragment-shaders)

Comment: Yesterday I [filed an issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/6829) and a user had begun helping me and identifying the issue and potential solutions

Comment: As regards my GPU, it's Nvidia GTX 1080Ti 11GB VRAM

Comment: @instadrum Can you take a look into the issue?